How can I only accept numbers in the TextField and max 1 number als input from user? (Kotlin)
//2 dimensional array mit default size 4
var gridSize by remember { mutableStateOf(4) }
var grid by remember { mutableStateOf(Array(gridSize) { Array(gridSize) { TextFieldValue("") } }) }

Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
//looping through rows & columns
    for (i in grid.indices) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            for (j in grid[i].indices) {
                // Render each cell as TextField
                TextField(
                    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
                    value = grid[i][j],
                    onValueChange = { newValue ->
                        // cell value in grid update
                        grid = grid.copyOf().also { it[i][j] = newValue }
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(4.dp)
                        .weight(1f)
                )
            }
        }
    }

I tried adding the keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number), doesnt work
